# PDFsharp & MigraDoc: PDF layout page ending

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am using PDFsharp and MigraDoc to create PDF documents. And yesterday I faced with problem of page ending. I have a loop with data for example for 10 items. In each iteration I need to create such document -> [image: pdf example]

And then save it as one PDF document. As we see I have several blocks on the page which can dynamically increase. How can I detect ending of the page end continue draw string on next page? And how can I detect ending of a first paragraph to add second (or just attach to the end)? I tried use paragraph.AddText() and it doesn't continue on the next page, just go into nowhere. From documentation of PDFsharp and MigraDoc I can’t find correspondent example. Here is my attempts to do it for one iteration [download example](https://yadi.sk/d/WgZprdTZzqLaY), [example 2 download](https://yadi.sk/d/jLtYHSsazqQsh). I will be very grateful for some pieces of code which can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You do not show any code. You mention `AddText()` so I assume you use MigraDoc.

The MigraDoc samples can be found here:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocSamples.ashx

With MigraDoc you normally do not have to care about page breaks as MigraDoc will break paragraphs to the next page automatically. At least this is the default behavior when you use `renderer.RenderDocument()` to create the document.
You can use `Section.AddPageBreak()` to force a page break when needed.

See this example for recommended use of MigraDoc and `RenderDocument()`:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx

Comment: For the moment I don't have any correct part of code for generating that pdf. I am trying to use samples but on all of them I have similar problem. On of the examples explains how to use it when you have a lot of lines, but in comment to the sample author said, if you have line breaks it sample not for you.  This is what I am trying to correct for myself now [link to sample](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MixMigraDocAndPdfSharp-sample.ashx). In general I have only loop, each item of which I need to populate to such document as I provided. Thank you.

Comment: as example of my previous attempts I can share this console app. It is example for one iteration [download](https://yadi.sk/d/WgZprdTZzqLaY) inside archive near to sln you can find txt document with data.

Comment: The "Mix MigraDoc and PDFsharp" sample shows a special case where you are responsible for page breaks. Use MigraDoc as shown in the other samples (with `renderer.RenderDocument()`) and you will get automatic page breaks.